# Calculating linear returns in R

Tags: r, finance

I have what i assume is an incredibly easy problem to solve, but i just cant figure out what is wrong. My goal is to calculate linear stock returns, but the code below simply returns a straight line when trying to plot the linear returns. Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize in advance for my ignorance if it turns out to be something stupid, I am a complete beginner in R and coding in general.

````
    ```{r}
dataFF = read.csv("FF_Data_2016_11.csv", header = T, sep = ";")
dataFF$Date = dataFF$X.1 %/% 100 + (dataFF$X.1 %% 100 - 1) /12
dataFF[,3:(ncol(dataFF)-1)] = dataFF[,3:(ncol(dataFF)-1)] * 0.01
```

```{r}
dataie = read.csv("ie_data2016_11.csv", header = T, sep = ";", dec = ".", skip = 7, nrows = 1751)
dataie = as.data.frame(dataie[1:1751,1:11])
tsdata = ts(dataie, start = c(1871,1), frequency = 12)
dataie$date = seq(from = tsp(tsdata)[1], to = tsp(tsdata)[2], length.out = nrow(tsdata))
dataie = na.omit(dataie)
```

```{r}
# (log price, log div, YTM, div/monthly, Div/Price, log D/P)
dataie$log_p = log(dataie$P)
dataie$log_d = log(dataie$DIV)

dataie$ytm = dataie$GS10/100
dataie$div_m = dataie$DIV/12
dataie$DP = dataie$div_m/dataie$P
dataie$log_DP = log(dataie$DP)

```

```{r}
# linear monthly R with/without div
dataie$r_lin = dataie$P/lag(dataie$P,1)-1
dataie$r_linD = (dataie$P+dataie$div_m)/lag(dataie$P, -1)-1
````

Sample data:

```
 Date    P   DIV      E      CPI Fraction     GS10    Price Dividend
1881.01 6.19 0.265 0.4858 9.419420 1881.042 3.700000 158.9405 6.804400
1881.02 6.17 0.270 0.4817 9.514585 1881.125 3.693333 156.8424 6.863442
1881.03 6.24 0.275 0.4775 9.514585 1881.208 3.686667 158.6218 6.990543
1881.04 6.22 0.280 0.4733 9.609669 1881.292 3.680000 156.5489 7.047217

div_m          DP    log_DP r_lin      r_linD
0.02208333 0.003567582 -5.635867     0 0.003567582
0.02250000 0.003646677 -5.613939     0 0.003646677
0.02291667 0.003672543 -5.606871     0 0.003672543
0.02333333 0.003751340 -5.585642     0 0.003751340
```

Comment: got any sample data?

Comment: Yes, i have edited the original question with a sample

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `lag` operator. It does not work with `data.frame`s

For example:

```
df=data.frame(x=1:4)
df$lx=lag(df$x)
df
  x lx
1 1  1
2 2  2
3 3  3
4 4  4
```

You need to define your data as a time series to use the `lag` operator. Using `xts` and your `Date` column:

```
library(xts)
dataie=xts(dataie,order.by=as.Date(paste(dataie$Date,"01",sep="."),format="%Y.%m.%d"))

# linear monthly R with/without div
dataie$r_lin = dataie$P/lag(dataie$P,1)-1
dataie$r_linD = (dataie$P+dataie$div_m)/lag(dataie$P)-1

> dataie[,c(1:3,15:17)]
              Date    P   DIV    log_DP        r_lin       r_linD
1881-01-01 1881.01 6.19 0.265 -5.635867           NA           NA
1881-02-01 1881.02 6.17 0.270 -5.613939 -0.003231018 0.0004038772
1881-03-01 1881.03 6.24 0.275 -5.606871  0.011345219 0.0150594273
1881-04-01 1881.04 6.22 0.280 -5.585642 -0.003205128 0.0005341880
```